# Flutter prevent widget rebuild

Tags: flutter

When i select `TextField()`(means keyboard open) my widget tree rebuilt.
I know the reason for this is because when the keyboard is opened, the screen sizes change and the whole class is rebuilt (both StateFull and Stateless widgets). And this is normal.
**And so the `AnimatedList()` in my class is rebuilt. I do not want it to be rebuilt (because list indexes and list items in it change). How can I prevent this `AnimatedList()` Widget  rebuilt? Or is it possible to prevent the class from being rebuilt when the keyboard is opened in general?**

*Please Help Me*

**Here my code:**

```
class CommentPage extends StatelessWidget {
final String activityname;
final String postid;
final String usernameuid;

const CommentPage({
Key key,
@required this.activityname,
@required this.postid,
@required this.usernameuid,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    height: 400,
    child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Coments'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 350,
        width: 300,
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CommentLikeController(),
          builder: (context, child) => FutureBuilder<List<Comment>>(
              future:
                  Provider.of<CommentLikeController>(context, listen: false)
                      .initial(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData)
                  return Stack(children: [
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 50,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 350,
                        width: 300,
                        child: AnimatedList(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          reverse: true,
                          key: Provider.of<CommentLikeController>(context)
                              .listkey,
                          initialItemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                            return ListItem(
                              index: index,
                              postid: postid,
                              activityname: activityname,
                              usernameuid: usernameuid,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 350,
                        child: TextField(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
                else
                  return LinearProgressIndicator();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another `StatefulWidget` and place your `TextField` widget inside it. Create the text field `controller` in your `CommentPage` and pass it as parameter to your new created StatefulWidget and use it as the the TextField's controller. The keyboard effect will only impact the new created StatefulWidget